# can i use dimdim for web based video chat

Tags: video-streaming

I want to know how can i have my own web based video chat service similar to gmail chat/video chat.
I have come to know that we can use dimdim open source project for this purpose.

All i want to provide a video chat option to the users, when they are chatting online. similar to commetchat option, though they use tokbox. But i want my own video server to work that way.

.

All replies are welcome.

Best Regards,

James

Answer (score 0):

dimdim is bought by salesforce  doesnt look like its opensource anymore: http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2011/01/110106.jsp

Comment: look how old this is: 2009, 2008,  thats not the last version of dimdim, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimdim#Open_source

Comment: Dimdim has come under heavy criticism lately by a large section of the community for not releasing an open source version after the 4.5 version. It has been accused of using open source as a means of publicity but never actually being committed to the community. The lack of a proper public repository and no communication between the developers and the community further questions the intent.[citation needed]

Comment: As of December 2010, at Dimdim's website, there was no download available for the open source version and the only way to download it was from SourceForge.net. Dimdim's acquisition FAQ states that the company would no longer be contributing to the open source project.[8] As of January 2011, an open source fork called miDmiD had been started.[8]

Comment: so, guys how can i achieve my goal to provide free video chat to my users.. i know it sounds weird but is there any other way or any other software module to start with.....

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to use openTok / Tokbox probably